# Bootstrap - navbar changes not working when applied in navbar.less

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, navbar

I am trying to update the style of my navbar in Bootstrap. This is easy if I just make a new file main.css, import bootstrap.min.css, and add the properties I want:

```
//     main.css

.navbar-header {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

However, when I try to put the same properties in navbar.less and then compile it (instead of using main.css), the changes don't work:

```
//     bootstrap/less/navbar.less

.navbar-header {
    // BEGIN CUSTOM STYLES

    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;

    // END CUSTOM STYLES

    &:extend(.clearfix all);

    @media (min-width: @grid-float-breakpoint) {
        float: left;
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue regarding grunt. I was using bootstrap.min.css in my page, and grunt was not minifying the compiled bootstrap.css.

I was using `grunt watch` to compile the files automatically. However, the default grunt configuration I was using did not run the css:minifyCore task. Thus, I had to update a section in Gruntfile.js from this:

```
watch: {
  src: {
    files: '<%= jshint.core.src %>',
    tasks: ['jshint:src', 'qunit', 'concat']
  },
  test: {
    files: '<%= jshint.test.src %>',
    tasks: ['jshint:test', 'qunit']
  },
  less: {
    files: 'less/**/*.less',
    tasks: 'less'
  }
},
```

to this:

```
watch: {
  src: {
    files: '<%= jshint.core.src %>',
    tasks: ['jshint:src', 'qunit', 'concat']
  },
  test: {
    files: '<%= jshint.test.src %>',
    tasks: ['jshint:test', 'qunit']
  },
  less: {
    files: 'less/**/*.less',
    tasks: ['less', 'cssmin:minifyCore']
  }
},
```